# Is there a code to auto/complete OS login on Windows Virtual Instance on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, rdp

I have to start and run Java applications using windows scheduler on my Google Cloud Virtual Instance. I have google cloud functions, Pub/subs and cloud scheduler set up to start the instance at a certain time. I am looking for a way to auto log into the OS with out any intervention and start the Java application using the window scheduler. Is there a way to do that?

I do not want to use scheduler without logon to run the java application in windows 10.

If I use the scheduler to start the function. I am unable to see the ongoing program even after I log in.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a [Startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script_for_windows_instances) to initialize your Java application. Either way use a cmd or a bat startup script.

Comment: This won't work if you have a script that performs UI interactions. For that you must automate RDP login